# Где можно прочитать доходчивое описание алгоритма LR(1)-анализатора?

Tags: алгоритм, компиляция

Мне нужно написать программу, которая читает из текстового файла LR(1)-грамматику и по ней проверяет некоторый текст.

В учебнике описан алгоритм, но это сделано через математические описания и выглядит довольно сложно для понимания.

Comment: @InfernumDeus, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Если есть время, почитайте классику: «Алгоритмы + структуры данных = программы» Никлауса Вирта (легко гуглится). Там есть целая глава, посвящённая автоматическому разбору LR(1)-грамматики, и дан пример программы, делающей именно то, что вам нужно. (Теоретическую часть можно при первом чтении пропустить или быстро пробежать.)

Я учился писать парсеры по этой книге.

---

**Обновление**

Ох. Я перепутал LR(1) и LL(1). Если вам нужна именно LR(1)-грамматика, это гораздо сложнее. Тогда почитайте про lex/yacc (опять-таки, книги есть в интернете), эти утилиты работают с LALR(1), что является упрощённым вариантом LR(1). Если вам нужно написать подобные утилиты самому и поддерживать именно LR(1), придётся постараться.

И «быстро» разобраться с проблемой не получится. Потребуйте с заказчика много денег, это серьёзная задача. Если вы работаете за зарплату, потребуйте позицию сениора.

Comment: Спасибо. Завтра посмотрю. Времени условно мало, поэтому и ищу наиболее доходчивое описание. Пока не принимаю ответ. Возможно, успеют ещё что-нибудь посоветовать.

Comment: @InfernumDeus, а  в [вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80) (конечно, с учетом чтения по ссылкам там) что именно не понятно?

Comment: @InfernumDeus: Обновил ответ. Всё на самом деле гораздо более сложно.

Comment: @avp, имеете в виду внутренние ссылки? Это не то. Мне нужно четкое описание алгоритма.

Comment: Это задание из вузовского курса. Однако, серьёзным вещам учат.

Comment: @InfernumDeus: Ого. Ничего так вуз у вас.

Comment: @InfernumDeus, а [здесь](http://ict.edu.ru/ft/005128//ch7.pdf) смотрели?

(вторая ссылка гугла на запрос

    lr(1) анализатор

на первый взгляд вроде бы понятно).

Comment: @avp, да. У меня, всё же, какое-никакое, а конкретное описание алгоритма анализа. Похоже, лучше моего учебника нет, хех. Учебник из ТУСУРа, В.Т. Калайды и В.В. Романенко.